# Is it possible to have 2 BizTalk Server nodes running off of a single MessageBox?

Tags: biztalk

Myself and my colleagues are currently in the process of upgrading our BizTalk environment to BT 2020 from BT 2013R2 and as part of this we are intending on setting up two BizTalk servers so that we can have host instances running across both of them. We do not, however, need more than one MessageBox DB based on the load we see, and after looking online, there doesn't seem to be a breadth of information.

Is it possible to have our BT setup to have 2 servers running off of a single MessageBox and is it complicated to configure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s the basic feature of BizTalk to have multi servers group connected to same message box. On your second computer, when you configure BizTalk using BizTalk Configuration Wizard, you choose option to join existing group and you should select your existing dbs to join.

Microsoft Docs [Install BizTalk Server in a Multi-Computer Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/install-and-config-guides/install-biztalk-server-in-a-multi-computer-environment)